# Trying to bulk remove in notepad++

Tags: replace, notepad++

I am trying to remove some data in a about 1500 lines. Here is my problem

```
            <a href="http:www.example.com">Text</a><br />random text<br />
            <a href="http:www.example.com">Text</a><br />slight different random text to the above<br />
            <a href="http:www.example.com">Text</a><br />slightly different again random text the above 2<br />
```

What i need to do is remove

```
            <br />slightly different again random text the above 2<br />
```

And everything in it. The problem is that the text changes every time. Is there a wildcard variable that i can use in the replace function?

Comment: You could replace everything between `<br />` and `\n`... though I don't know much about notepad++'s functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Use regular expressions" option in the Find and Replace dialog. You'll need something like:

```
<br />.+?<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regular expression in the find and replace dialog box

```
(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+[a-zA-Z]*(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+
```